# Connecting to a neo4 driver (in a Docker container) from another Docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, neo4j

Normally I'd have an instance neo4j running in Docker, then in a script I access the driver like so:

```
self.driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri="bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("username", "password"))
```

I'm now putting this script itself into a Docker container, but I now get the error message:

```
neo4j.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: Failed to establish connection to IPv6Address(('::1', 7687, 0, 0)) (reason [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)
```

What uri (or other parameter) needs changing to access a neo4 Docker instance, from another docker container?

Within my docker-compose.yml, I have:

```
version: '3'

services:
  neo4j:
    container_name: neo4j
    image: neo4j:3.5
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=2G
      - dbms_connector_bolt_tls__level=OPTIONAL
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size=3500M
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/start
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/data:/data
      - $HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs
      - $HOME/neo4j/import:/import
      - $HOME/neo4j/plugins:/plugins
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
  appgui:
    container_name: appgui
    image: python:3.7.3-slim
    build:
      context: ./APPGUI/
    volumes:
      - ./APPGUI/:/usr/src/app/
    restart: always
    environment:
      PORT: 5000
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - neo4j
```

I also can't access my web app (http://localhost:5000)

Comment: `localhost` in Docker usually means "this container".  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes the hostnames you need to use to connect to other containers.

Comment: @DavidMaze: the problem I now get after executing "after executing docker-compose up " is "appgui exited with code 0". The neo4j docker container works ( http://localhost:7474/) but the same for web app doesn't (http://localhost:5000/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service can't connect to localhost Neo4j, because it is inside a docker container, and localhost points to the docker containers instead of your local machine.
In this case, it is best to run both containers with docker-compose. You want to set the depends on feature in the other docker container. Here is an example `docker-compose.yml` file from my project.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:4.1.2
    restart: always
    hostname: neo4jngs
    container_name: neo4jngs
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
  api:
    build:
      context: ./API
    hostname: api
    restart: always
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
        - neo4j
```

As you can see, the api container is a service that will connect to Neo4j. Now you can change the driver settings to:

```
self.driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri="bolt://neo4j:7687", auth=("username", "password"))
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I think the answer is half way there. Actually I updated my original post. I'm using docker-compose.yml, but it wasn't configured to how you have yours. So I made some changes. I tried to load up the page with http://localhost:5000 but it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: I also got "appgui exited with code 0" after executing docker-compose up

Answer (score 0):

I solved it and it was actually a dumb mistake, but one that could happen to others I guess...
In the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
build: ./APP1/
```

needs to be in quotes, so:

```
build: './APP1/'
```

However Tomaž Bratanič provided me with some helpful tips to get a resolve.